# Prolog - Parser Fails when using Unary Minus

Tags: parsing, prolog, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I am making an arithmetic parser for an example grammar in Prolog, which takes in a list of tokens and returns an AST to feed into `is/2`, but I'm stumped on implementing unary minus. So far as I can tell, all other parts are working in the following code, except unary minus.

```
expr(Expr) --> term(Term), exprLoop(Term, Expr).

exprLoop(Term, ExprLoop) --> [+], term(Term2), exprLoop(Term + Term2, ExprLoop).
exprLoop(Term, ExprLoop) --> [-], term(Term2), exprLoop(Term - Term2, ExprLoop).
exprLoop(ExprLoop, ExprLoop) --> [].

term(Term) --> factor(Factor), termLoop(Factor, Term).

termLoop(Factor, TermLoop) --> [*], factor(Factor2), termLoop(Factor * Factor2, TermLoop).
termLoop(Factor, TermLoop) --> [/], factor(Factor2), termLoop(Factor / Factor2, TermLoop).
termLoop(TermLoop, TermLoop) --> [].

factor(Factor) --> [-], factor(-Factor).
factor(Factor) --> ['('], expr(Factor), [')'].
factor(Factor) --> [ Factor ], { integer(Factor) }.

parse(Tokens, Ast) :-
  phrase(expr(Ast), Tokens, []).
```

When parsing an expression without a unary minus, it functions normally, but returns false when a statement has a unary minus. Removing the `-` from `-Factor` in `factor(Factor) --> [-], factor(-Factor).`, `parse` succeeds but obviously gives the wrong result. I am mostly confused as to why `-` in `-Factor` causes the parser to fail, while similar arithmetic on the arguments of `exprLoop` and `termLoop` functions normally.

Comment: Try to use ```factor(-Factor) --> [-], factor(Factor).```, instead of ```factor(Factor) --> [-], factor(-Factor).```.

Comment: Oh, that was simple. I hadn't thought to use pattern matching in the arguments of `-->` rules, but I should've thought to considering they're just macros. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

As per slago:

> Try to use `factor(-Factor) --> [-], factor(Factor).`, instead of `factor(Factor) --> [-], factor(-Factor).`